# How to replace correlated subquery with non-correlated subquery?

Tags: sql, performance, subquery, informix

i have a query with bad performance because of `correlated subquery` and i want to replace it wiz 
`non-correlated subquery` .How to do this :

My query :

```
select a.emp_num, a.name , b.cont_date 
from main_emp a INNER JOIN main_cont b
ON a.emp_num = b.emp_num AND a.calc_year = b.calc_year 

join 
(
    select emp_num,calc_year, max(bb.cont_date) AS max_date from main_cont bb
    GROUP BY emp_num,calc_year
)   bb_max
on a.emp_num =  bb_max.emp_num and a.calc_year = bb_max.calc_year and b.cont_date = bb_max.max_date

where
( 0 = ( select count(*) from main_serv x where x.emp_num = a.emp_num and x.calc_year = a.calc_year ) 
    or b.cont_date >  ( select max(y.ser_date) from main_serv y where y.emp_num = a.emp_num and y.calc_year = a.calc_year) ) -- The problem here
and a.calc_year = 2015
order by 1
```

---

Now i want to convert this subquery :

```
  ( 0 = ( select count(*) from main_serv x where x.emp_num = a.emp_num and x.calc_year = a.calc_year ) 
        or b.cont_date >  ( select max(y.ser_date) from main_serv y where y.emp_num = a.emp_num and y.calc_year = a.calc_year) )
```

To

Join like this :

```
 join 
    (
        select emp_num,calc_year, max(bb.cont_date) AS max_date from main_cont bb
        GROUP BY emp_num,calc_year
    )   bb_max
    on a.emp_num =  bb_max.emp_num and a.calc_year = bb_max.calc_year and b.cont_date = bb_max.max_date
```

But i don't how to do this because i have `((0 =(subquery) OR (subquery))`

Comment: You can do this: `INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT count(*) AS count, max(y.ser_date) AS MaxDate
from main_serv x 
where x.emp_num = a.emp_num and x.calc_year = a.calc_year
) tt ON tt.count = 0 AND b.cont_date < tt.MaxDate`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: but i have `OR` not `AND`

Comment: and `b.cont_date >` not `<`

Comment: Whatever the condition, you can put any condition in the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: the `( 0 = ( select count(*) ...` can be rewritten as a `NOT EXISTS ...` , which technically still is a correlated subquery (anti-join) but much clearer IMO.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal :`x.emp_num = a.emp_num and x.calc_year = a.calc_year`
still correlated subquery

Comment: Why? Just move them to the `JOIN` condition like this: `INNER JOIN 
( 
   SELECT count(*) AS count, max(y.ser_date) AS MaxDate 
   from main_serv 
) x ON x.count = 0 OR b.cont_date > x.MaxDate AND x.emp_num = a.emp_num and x.calc_year = a.calc_year`

Comment: ... and the subsub query `b.cont_date >  ( select max(y.ser_date)` will magically transform into a part of the WHERE clause in the first subquery.

Comment: I will be grateful if u write the whole query as an answer please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
  a.emp_num, 
  a.name, 
  b.cont_date 
FROM main_emp a 
INNER JOIN main_cont b ON a.emp_num = b.emp_num AND a.calc_year = b.calc_year 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT emp_num,calc_year, max(bb.cont_date) AS max_date 
    from main_cont bb
    GROUP BY emp_num,calc_year
)   bb_max
on a.emp_num =  bb_max.emp_num and a.calc_year = bb_max.calc_year 
                               and b.cont_date = bb_max.max_date
INNER JOIN 
( 
   SELECT emp_num, calc_year, count(*) AS count, max(ser_date) AS MaxDate 
   from main_serv 
   WHERE calc_year IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY emp_num, calc_year
) x ON x.count = 0 OR b.cont_date > x.MaxDate 
    AND x.emp_num = a.emp_num 
    AND x.calc_year = a.calc_year
where a.calc_year = 2015
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
but i get now rows!! in contrast of the subquery !
i guess the reason is `calc_year` is null in `main_serv` table

Comment: @just_name - Try to add `WHERE calc_year IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this part of your WHERE clause

```
( 0 = ( select count(*) from main_serv x where x.emp_num = a.emp_num and x.calc_year = a.calc_year ) 
    or b.cont_date >  ( select max(y.ser_date) from main_serv y where y.emp_num = a.emp_num and y.calc_year = a.calc_year) )
```

could be rendered as

> There are no rows in `main_serv`
>   OR
>   There are no rows in `main_serv` where `ser_date` is equal to or greater than `b.cont_date`.

I believe the second part of the disjunction covers the complete condition, because when there are no rows in `main_serv`, there will certainly be no rows matching the second part of the condition, and if there are any rows in `main_serv`, it will be the second part of the condition that will determine the result. So, I would rewrite the entire disjunctive part like this:

```
not exists (
  select *
  from main_serv as x
  where x.emp_num = a.emp_num
    and x.calc_year = a.calc_year
    and x.ser_date >= b.cont_date
)
```

This subquery is still correlated to the main query but it will not perform any aggregation and may overall be an improvement over your version anyway.